# Comparing values in two columns

Tags: python, finance

Now I have a large data set of stocks (2GB):

```python
    StockID       date    Industry code 1     Industry code 2       
0   10000   1986-01-06     NaN                 399        
1   10000   1986-01-07     NaN                 399         
2   10000   1986-01-08     NaN                 399  
3   10000   1986-01-09     NaN                 399  
...
```

I want to check two things,

1. if a stock entity has ever changed its `Industry code 1` or `Industry code 2`
2. if a stock entity is categorized into finance industry in one industry code but not in the other.(i.e. `['Industry code 1']=52` or `53` when `['Industry code 2']!=60` to `70` or vice versa)

Comment: Hi, please explain how you can answer the first question (about entity change) from the data.

Comment: Hi, for the first question what I wanna do is to make sure that every company stays in the same industry since it went public.

Answer (score 2):

Your first question is not possible unless you have a history of the data. If you have a history, then all you would have to do is check if the current dataframe value and the old value are the same, and if they are not, that means the entity has changed.

For your second question, if you are using a library like pandas, and your dataframe is stored in a variable df, then you can check for specific situations with the following:

```
df[(df['Industry code 1'] == 52 | df['Industry code 1'] == 53) & (df['Industry code 2'] < 60 | df['Industry code 2'] > 70)]
```

This code is specific to the example you gave, but you can modify it to fit whatever subset you want to create. This gives you a subset that you can then do whatever you want with (see which stock entities follow this pattern, how many in total, etc.).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! For the first question what I wanna do is to make sure that every company stays in the same industry since it went public. You may have the misunderstanding that I want to know if any updates have been made to the dataset.